# How to resolve Qt Creator variable-“<not accessible>” behavior (Opencv)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

[image]

As observed in the screenshot above, I have the problem that variables in the *Locals and Expressions* window in QT Creator are displayed as being .  How can I get Qt Creator to show the values for the OpenCV filter functions?

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator marks "not accessible" for the value, not for the variable. That means those variables are not initialized yet. Try to inspect the same values by adding another debugging point after the matrices are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this for a struct I had defined.  I could see the contents of other structs, but not this particular one.  It turned out that I was declaring the struct inside a function in my main window object.  I just had to take the struct out of the function, just declaring it at global level before the function (not even bothering to put it in the header, although that's better practice).  That was enough to allow me to see the values of a QList, that is itself still declared in the function in question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with gdb when the value size is too big.  You can type the gdb command, set max-value-size 1048576, in the gdb prompt to increase the max value size.

You can also configure it in the Debugger -> GDB -> Additional Startup Commands.